# The best practice for writing Django apps while optimize ORM queries?

Tags: django, optimization, orm

Writing a complex django apps involves playing with ORM objects in different places (views, templates, etc). However, designing ORM models is usually done in the beginning of project. On that stage is very difficult to predict exactly how data will be queried (what ForeignKeys will be used mostly).

There are many stages where we can optimise number of queries that ORM makes:

- select_related() - in given ORM call
- prefetch_related() - in given ORM call
- overriding models ModelManager to prefetch all related models for all queries

My usual way to optimise this is to write my whole app, and then using Developer Toolbar, see how many queries it is produced for a given view, and then decide where did they come from and how to avoid them (using above-mentioned options).

But I found this way of doing that error-prone (e.g. you can forget to examine all views, or other background /celery/ methods). However, I found also very hard an inefficient doing optimisation while writing a logic (because I want to focus on logic, not on ORM calls at that moment).

So my question is - what is the best practice (the best moment for) optimizing ORM queries?

Answer (score 1):

They say premature optimization is the root of all evil. You should start worrying about optimization when things get slow (even if we all know they eventually will).
Checking manually every view with Django Debug Toolbar is in fact more error prone than, say, a more automated test.
A first approach can be collecting some metrics through [django-timelog](https://github.com/garethr/django-timelog), and then use DDT starting from the slower views.